# Running Django on CentOS?

Tags: centos, python, django

I have a problem running Django with mod_wsgi and Apache on CentOS.

Django runs on Python 2.5 or above but CentOS comes with Python 2.4. I can't just upgrade the default Python 2.4 because it breaks other services such as `yum`. I installed Python 2.7 into different directory.

I followed most of the tutorial and article about running Django with mod_wsgi but never able successfully run it.

Does any of you run Django on CentOS successfully? If so, how did you do it?

Comment: This should be doable, but even an incredibly in-depth answer can't practically cover every issue you might have - which is why we like questions to cover a specific problem, instead of an entire subject.  Can you edit your question to include specific issues or errors that you've run into, what steps you've tried, and what your config looks like now?

Answer (score 1):

Try virualenv. That should do it.

Here is a nice write up on virtualenv: http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/

Comment: Using a virtual environment is not enough as mod_wsgi must be compiled against the correct Python version you want to use. You can't just tell it to use a virtual environment from a different Python version.